# Uniqueness of theta divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, divisors

Let $A$ be an abelian variety (at least over $\mathbb{C}$). Suppose we have two theta divisors $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ on $A$, which give two principal polarizations on $A$.

In general, are those two divisors the same, up to something?
In other words, is a principal polarization unique, if exists?

**Edit:** the question was edited following comments.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Indeed, the theta divisor is unique up to translation, essentially by definition. See any book on abelian varieties, for instance Birkenhake-Lange.

Comment: @abx I'm sorry I don't get it! For me a theta divisor is a divisor whose associated line bundle gives a principal polarization. From that, how can I prove the uniqueness?

Comment: The line bundle satisfies $h^0(\mathscr{O}_A(\Theta ))=1$, hence it corresponds to a *unique* effective divisor. And a polarization defines the corresponding line bundle up to translation.

Comment: Are you asking whether an abelian variety has a unique principal polarization, if one exists? The answer is no. You'll find examples by searching for non-isomorphic curves with isomorphic jacobians, for instance.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Yes, my question is: if I have two theta divisor on $A$, do they end up being the same (up to something)?

Comment: I think @abx misunderstood your question. As I said, the answer is no.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch: Indeed I probably misunderstood the question, which is far from clear.

Comment: I think maybe the terminology is confusing. Are you using *theta divisor* as a synonym for *a divisor that gives a principal polarization* on an arbitrary abelian variety? Then you'll find lots of counterexamples that are not algebraically equivalent. Or are you using it to be a translate of the image of $C^{g-1}$ in its Jacobian variety?

Comment: @JoeSilverman By theta divisor I mean a divisor whose associated ample line bundle gives a principal polarization. I'm not interested in Jacobian varieties.

Comment: By  M.S. NARASIMHAN AND M. V. NORI, Polarizations on an abelian variety, Proc. Indian Accad. Sci. Math. Sci. 90 (1981) No. 2, 125-128.  any abelian variety admits only a finite number of principal polarizations up to isomorphism. To compute the number of these isomorphism classe, see "Abelian varieties with several principal polarizations" by
Herbert Lange available at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077306167

Comment: Thanks @Hacon for the useful comment! I'll check it out